# XQuery: tokenizing text while preserving tags

Tags: xquery, tokenize

Consider the following XQuery code:

```
let $foo := <root>This is a <tag>test</tag>. This is <tag>only</tag> a <tag>test</tag>.</root>
for $s in tokenize($foo, "\. ")
return <sentence>{$s}</sentence>
```

It returns `$foo` split (very naively) into sentences — but it also strips out the tags contained within `$foo`:

```
<sentence>this is a test.</sentence>
<sentence>this is only a test.</sentence>
```

Suppose I want to split `$foo` into sentences while *preserving* embedded tags, giving output that looks like the following:

```
<sentence>this is a <tag>test</tag>.</sentence>
<sentence>this is <tag>only</tag> a <tag>test</tag>.</sentence>
```

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is what are you looking for:

```
let $foo := <root>This is a <tag>test</tag>. This is <tag>only</tag> a <tag>test</tag>.</root>
for $s in tokenize(xdmp:quote($foo/node()), "\. ")
return xdmp:unquote("<sentence>"||$s||"</sentence>")
```